# Unable to load model in controller of zend framework

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am getting below error when trying to load model in a controller
**Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_Adminlogin' not found in /var/www/html/ZendTecAdmin/application/controllers/AdminController.php on line 27**

Below is the controller
AdminController.php

```
<?php

class AdminController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function init() {

        $this->_helper->layout->setLayout('layout_admin');
        //$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($view->getBaseUrl.'js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js');
        //$this->view->headScript()->appendFile($view->getBaseUrl.'js/validate.js');
    }

    public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Welcome';
    }

    public function loginAction() {
        $mysession = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Admin');                
        $form = new Application_Form_loginForm();
        $this->view->form = $form;
    //Preform Admin login action
        if($this->_request->getPost('Login')){
            $formData=$this->_request->getPost();
            if($form->isValid($formData)){ //If form data is valid
                $name=$this->_request->getPost('username');
                $password=$this->_request->getPost('password');
                /****Creating object of model adminlogin class*****/
                               $adminLoginObj=new Admin_Model_Adminlogin();
                $fetchResult=$adminLoginObj->checkAdminAuthority($name,$password);
                if(count($fetchResult)>0){
                    $mysession->adminName=$name;
                    $this->_redirect('/admin/');
                }else{
                    $mysession->failLogin="Invalid Username or Password!";
                    $this->_redirect('/admin/login');

                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Following is Application.ini

```
[production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 0
phpSettings.display_errors = 0
includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"
bootstrap.path = APPLICATION_PATH "/Bootstrap.php"
bootstrap.class = "Bootstrap"
appnamespace = "Application"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 0

resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.db.adapter = "PDO_MYSQL"
resources.db.params.host = "localhost"
resources.db.params.username = "root"
resources.db.params.password = "root123"
resources.db.params.dbname = "quickstat"
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
resources.layout.layoutPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/layouts/scripts/"
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/ZendTecAdmin/"

resources.session.remember_me_seconds = 864000

[staging : production]

[testing : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1

[development : production]
phpSettings.display_startup_errors = 1
phpSettings.display_errors = 1
resources.frontController.params.displayExceptions = 1


resources.db.params.profiler.enabled = true
resources.db.params.profiler.class = Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug
includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/"
```

And model
application/models/Admin.php

```
<?php
    class Admin_Model_Adminlogin extends Zend_Db_Table{
        /* The Model Class Will be associated with register table*/

        protected $_name='users';

        function checkAdminAuthority($name,$pasword){
            $where="username='".$name."' and password='".$pasword."'";
            return $row=$this->fetchRow($where);
        }

    }
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update file name and class name as below,

File name : `AdminLogin.php`

Class name : `Application_Model_Adminlogin`

```
class Application_Model_Adminlogin extends Zend_Db_Table{
```

Create object as

```
$adminLoginObj = new Application_Model_Adminlogin();
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yes Its working fine but found some other problem, 
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Exception' with message 'Resource matching "db" not found' in /var/www/html/ZendTecAdmin/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php:694

Answer (score 0):

if your model is model application/models/Admin.php
then class name for this model should be

```
 class Admin_Model_Admin
```

Comment: chnaged but Fatal error: Class 'Admin_Model_Admin' not found in /var/www/html/ZendTecAdmin/application/controllers/AdminController.php on line 27  table name adminlogin

Comment: oh sorry please try class Application_Model_Admin and let me know is it work or not and 
load model by using
$adminLoginObj=new Application_Model_Adminlogin();

Comment: is there anything missing in my application.ini file?

Comment: Application_Model_Adminlogin? shoule exist if we are trying to create object?

Comment: I canged to file Adminlogin.php and class name to Application_Model_Adminlogin Now I am getting some different error An error occurred Application error

Answer (score 0):

Your Model extends Zend_Db_table it should extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

```
class Admin_Model_Adminlogin extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
```

Comment: Can you try to do this:
In your Model:
class Application_Model_Adminlogin extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{

And in your Controller:

Comment: $adminLoginObj=new Application_Model_Adminlogin();

Comment: Maybe try to delete this in your application.ini: includePaths.models = APPLICATION_PATH "/models/"

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code for creating the model object :

```
$adminLoginObj = new Application_Model_Adminlogin();
```

Comment: please change class name "Admin_Model_Adminlogin" to  "Application_Model_Adminlogin"

Comment: If i create any class file inside model folder, i unable to create its object.

Comment: @MattWritesCode : same error exists. I got frustrated here, rest of the things working fine except model.

Comment: I canged to file Adminlogin.php and class name to Application_Model_Adminlogin Now I am getting some different error An error occurred
Application error